# confused about UIGraphicGetCurrentContext()

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

I am doing some customization and facing with

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

My question : what is the default size for this context and how the size of this context is defined.

Edit :

I am asking because I am following tutorial at [link1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) and at [link2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss)...

Please look at a context, when we have the background cell in red color from `link1` and the header section in red color as well from `link2`.

However, the width of these are not the same even though they are subclasses of `UIView` and I am getting lost to find out the reason...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your question, especially when Raywenderlich's tutorial states it very clearly.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Will give you the current "canvas", then you just change the state of that canvas.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGColorRef redColor = 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
```

The size IS defined by wherever you call the get context function, THAT function is being called inside the custom drawRect method, according to apples docs:

> The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its
>   drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack,
>   making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to do your
>   drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack
>   manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext function.

So when self.bounds is passed the size of the element that called this function is used.

This code can even be called for different cells of different sizes since every cell will call a drawRect method and will get the corresponding size.

Maybe your confusion is in the fact that they are subclasses of UIView, it doesn't mean that they have the "UIView" properties from the view in your storyboard. It means that they are elements which have the same structure as an uiview (which is why they can call drawRect) but that you will expand or customize for your desired behavior.

PD: Just noticed I answered another question of yours earlier today haha.